# Show files on default viewers without downloading from URL

Tags: android

I am having webservice which has a String URL response, URL could be of .PNG and .PDF I don't want to download image and pdf files from that url I want to show them on default viewer i.e. if i click to view image button then it should open image url to any default photo viewer and if i click to view pdf button then it should open pdf in default pdf viewer. 
Please help Thanks in advance.

```
    File file = new File(url);
    MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    String extension = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
    String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension); 
    newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        startActivity(newIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MasterPlan_Activity.this, "No handler for this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: post code you have already tried

Comment: File file = new File(url);
        MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Comment: String extension = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
        String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

Comment: newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        try {
            startActivity(newIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MasterPlan_Activity.this, "No handler for this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept here is opening an app that can handle your resource (**JPEG or PDF**). So, you need to request an **Implicit Intent** with the data URI that needs to be shown.
You can use intent with specific filter to achieve that, as shown below

Image:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/16"))); /** replace with your own uri */
```

Pdf:

```
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

or

```
private static final String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl + url), "text/html")
```

Comment: no, actually it will ask user to choose from all the apps that can handle .pfd url, browserintent is just name you can give any name to the intent

Comment: first it is redirecting me to browser and then start downloading the pdf

Comment: i have post my approach in above ans it is asking me for viewer but when i open it is generating error "file could not access check location"

Comment: Ok, that means the viewer expects an actual file on device's storage not an URL, so u can download the file in storage and than fire the intent with its uri, this way there will always be a file to be opened,

Comment: i have added another approach for opening pdf without downloading, you can check that out as well